# Replace Values in configurtation file using sed

Tags: bash, shell, awk, sed, sh

Conf.txt

```
Enable_FUN                                    Yes
FUN_Privilege_Level                           User
Force_FUN_Payload_Authentication              No
Force_FUN_Payload_Encryption                  No
Character_Accumulate_Interval                 12
Character_Send_Threshold                      96
FUN_Retry_Count                               7
FUN_Retry_Interval                            50
Non_Volatile_Bit_Rate                         115200
Volatile_Bit_Rate                             115200
```

I Need to Update the "Volatile_Bit_Rate" values from 115200 to 38400
Note: Volatile_Bit_Rate and  Non_Volatile_Bit_Rate has same matching string, also the format(spaces/tabs) should be unchanged.

I was trying in the below way, which works.

```
var=38400
sed -i "s/\bVolatile_Bit_Rate\b/Volatile_Bit_Rate    $var/" solconf
```

Then I need to delete the end of the strings.

But can anyone suggest me the regular expression in the below way which will be helpful.

```
sed -i "s/\bVolatile_Bit_Rate\b(expression for allspaces)(somenumbers) /Volatile_Bit_Rate(spaces)$var/" solconf
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do:

```
sed 's/\(^Volatile_Bit_Rate[[:blank:]]\+\)[0-9]\+$/\138400/' file.txt
```

To edit the file in place:

```
sed -i 's/\(^Volatile_Bit_Rate[[:blank:]]\+\)[0-9]\+$/\138400/' file.txt
```

**Example:**

```
$ cat file.txt
Enable_FUN                                    Yes
FUN_Privilege_Level                           User
Force_FUN_Payload_Authentication              No
Force_FUN_Payload_Encryption                  No
Character_Accumulate_Interval                 12
Character_Send_Threshold                      96
FUN_Retry_Count                               7
FUN_Retry_Interval                            50
Non_Volatile_Bit_Rate                         115200
Volatile_Bit_Rate                             115200

$ sed 's/\(^Volatile_Bit_Rate[[:blank:]]\+\)[0-9]\+$/\138400/' file.txt
Enable_FUN                                    Yes
FUN_Privilege_Level                           User
Force_FUN_Payload_Authentication              No
Force_FUN_Payload_Encryption                  No
Character_Accumulate_Interval                 12
Character_Send_Threshold                      96
FUN_Retry_Count                               7
FUN_Retry_Interval                            50
Non_Volatile_Bit_Rate                         115200
Volatile_Bit_Rate                             38400
```

Answer (score 2):

```
sed -ri "s/^(Volatile_Bit_Rate\s*)[0-9]+$/\1$var/g" file
```

Answer (score 0):

I found one simple answer for the above requirement,

sed "/\bVolatile_Bit_Rate\b/ s/\b38400\b/115200/g" conf

Answer (score 0):

Yet another variant:

```
var=38400
sed -i "/\bVolatile_Bit_Rate\b/s/[0-9]* *\$/$var/" solconf
```